# error: ambiguous default type conversion (c++)

Tags: c++, gcc

I have a class which wraps an enum for easy printing, serialization, etc.
I want to be able to use it in a switch statement as the traditional enum, hence I was using a int() overloader till gcc-4.3. However my code breaks now with **gcc-4.5.1**.

```
enum E { consta, constb };
class Wrap {
 private:
  E e;
 public:
  operator E() { return e;}
  operator E() const { return e;}
  operator int() const { return e;} 
  Wrap(E a) : e(a) { }
};

int main() {
  Wrap x(constb);
  x = consta;
  switch (x) { /* Error here */
    case consta: // ..
    case constb: // ..
  }   
  return 0;
}
```

Compiler errors are:
error: ambiguous default type conversion from 'Wrap'
error:   candidate conversions include 'Wrap::operator E() const' and 'Wrap::operator int() const'

This is part of a library and I want the code to work over all versions, hence removing the int overloader was not an option.

Comment: Why do you need the non-const `operator E()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're specifically working around compiler bugs, just use conditional compilation to create a workaround and keep it as self-contained as possible.

```
#if (__GNUC__ * 10000 + __GNUC_MINOR__ * 100 + __GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__) <= 40300
    typedef int E; // workaround
#   define ENUM_TYPE // do not define an enum type as it's not fully supported
#else
#   define ENUM_TYPE E // newer GCC supports enum better
#endif

enum ENUM_TYPE { consta, constb };
#undef ENUM_TYPE
```

… after this point, you can forget about the workaround, and only one operator is necessary …

```
  operator E() const { return e;}
```

Comment: I decided to use this as this is the least intrusive on the rest of the code base.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve the ambiguity by selecting the conversion yourself with a `static_cast`:

```
switch(static_cast<E>(x))
```

Another option would be to make one or more of the conversion operators `explicit` -- that would resolve the ambiguity by limiting the compiler's options.

However, `explicit` conversion operators are available only for C++0x, which your compiler  does not support.

Comment: `explicit` conversions are new in C++0x.

Comment: @Jon The `explicit` keyword does not work with gcc-4.3. Complains that only constructors can be `explicit`.

Comment: @nkarthiks: Then `switch(static_cast<E>(x))` will do it.

Comment: @Jon: Yes, but I'm trying to keep the cast as the last option. Looks like its the most compatible solution.

Comment: @nkarthiks, @JasmesMcNellis: Re-edited -- should have thought about `explicit` myself but I 'm not at all familiar with what GCC supports.

Comment: @nkarthiks: Either you remove (or hide) a conversion operator, or you call one explicitly (by using a cast). There is no third option.

Answer (score 0):

Change the line to

```
switch ((E)x) {
```

Enums and ints are very similar in the compiler (and probably identical in memory), so having both of those is confusing things. If you specifically cast it, here won't be any ambiguity in which you want to use.

Comment: I was trying to avoid explicitly casting all switch statements, and thats my last option :(

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't C++ allow you to automatically convert from an enum to `int`, rendering the `operator int` unneeded (for example, it would use the `E` conversion and then convert to `int`)? I know you said you don't want to remove it but did you actually confirm it breaks API compatibility?

If that's not an option probably the best bet is to add `as_int` and `as_E` methods to use in contexts where the desired conversion type is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

The spec says for the condition (switched-over value):

> The condition shall be of integral type, enumeration type, or of a class type for which a single conversion function to integral or enumeration type exists.

Your class type has 3 conversion functions to integral or enumeration types, so it easily fails this constraint. It won't even work if you remove the `operator int` overload, because then there are still 2 conversion functions. No overload resolution happens. There is also no need for a non-const `operator E` overload if it doesn't write anything anyway

An explicit cast will be a safe bet. Same rather weird way is to use `op+`, but which I wouldn't take for clarity reasons

```
switch (+x) { /* Don't do this in the wild */
  case consta: // ..
  case constb: // ..
}
```